# Selenium with Chrome and custom profile error

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

Is there a way to use specific profile for chrome browser, while controlling it with selenium with python bindings?

I have this sample script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Selenium')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/home/kossak/.config/google-chrome')

print('start')
wb = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
print('get')
wb.get('chrome://version')
print('end')
```

I can confirm that the browser is starting properly with proper profile selected (`/home/kossak/.config/google-chrome/Selenium`), but the script is stuck on `wb = webdriver...` line for about a minute and then displays exception, never executing the `print('get')` line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kossak/Kossak/files_common/PythonProjects/test/test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    wb = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "/home/kossak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/kossak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/kossak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/home/kossak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/kossak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 3.19.0-32-generic x86_64)
```

I noticed that when I don't use any custom profiles, chrome has extension "Chrome Browser Automation" addedd automatically (by selenium webdriver i guess). I tried creating another profile by copying the temp files from `/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.oTfMa3/Default` (temp folder created when you don't specify your own profile) but to no avail (and the copied profile was missing the CBA extension). I also tried installing [CBA](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-browser-automati/jmbmjnojfkcohdpkpjmeeijckfbebbon?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) manually with no luck either.

Any ideas how to make chrome automation work with custom profiles?
Thank you.

My os: Linux Mint 18 x64 "Sarah" Cinnamon
ChromeDriver 2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac)
Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit)
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06)
Selenium module 3.0.1

Comment: I just ran into the same problem: Chrome window comes up with my profile selected but after a little wait the script gets an exception: "unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)". Did you solve this by any chance?

Comment: No, i gave up custom profiles for now.